# Magento 2 How to show success message after product add to cart on home page?

Tags: product, magento2.3, javascript, catalog, home-page

How to show success message after product add to cart on home page like this "You added product-name to your shopping cart."
I am using that code on template file -

```
    <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                                <?php if(isset($_category_config['qty_field']) && $_category_config['qty_field']):?>
                                                    <div class="qty-box">
                                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qtyminus"><i class="porto-icon-minus"></i></a>
                                                        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"/>
                                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qtyplus"><i class="porto-icon-plus"></i></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                <?php endif;?>
                                                <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                                                <button type="submit"
                                                        title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart154')); ?>"
                                                        class="action tocart primary">
                                                    <span><?php echo __('Add to Cart154') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
 <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {}
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

example(like this on home page,this image is from category page) - [image]
Product is added successfully in cart but add to cart success message is not showing

Answer (score 0):

From where you doing add to cart? From a product details page, Or category page?

Comment: in my questions you can see i am talking about home page

Answer (score 0):

we need to assign a placeholder for the message through frontend layout xml used in the module as given below inside the  tag:

So add below layout code in you theme's

> Magento_CMS/layout/cms_index_index.xml

file inside body tag

```
<referenceContainer name="page.messages">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Or add in admin Content > Pages > and edit Home page and add above code in Design  > layout update scetion

Comment: not working,not showing message for add to cart